# My div is going down when rezise

Tags: html, css

i'm starting with responsive design and i'm having the next issue:

when i rezise my div, in a design of two column and the right one is going down.

**Ex before rezise:**

[image]

**and after rezise:**

[image]

I dont jnow why is going down f the design is in %. Maybe somebody can help'me, here the css code that i'm using.

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

h1 {font: bold 20px verdana, sans-serif; }

h2 {font: bold 14px verdana, sans-serif; }

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, figure, figcaption, hgroup { display: block; }

body { width: 100%; text-align: center; }

#envoltura { margin: 15px auto; text-align: left; padding: 0px 2% 0px 2%}

#cabecera { background: #FFFBB9; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 20px; text-align: center; }

#menu { background: #CCCCCC; padding: 5px 15px; text-align: center; }

#menu li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; padding: 5px; font: bold 14px verdana, sans-serif; }

#seccion { float: left; width: 65%; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; border: 2px solid #999999; padding: 2%; text-align: center; }

#lateral { float: left; width: 26.4%; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 2%; background: #CCCCCC; border: 2px solid #999999; text-align: center; }

#pie { clear: both; text-align: center; padding: 20px; border-top: 2px solid #999999; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't allowed enough room for the two columns at that window size!

► Declare different layout per media queries: 
*(method below based on a min and max screen resolution range)*

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  /* Your styles for between these two resolutions here */
}
```

**OR**! *depending on what you want to do, complete end goal, you may not even need to use media queries*

► Define width of each columns in a percentage relevant to either the browser, or a wrapper div.

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative; // the below is relative to this
  margin: 0 auto; // center
  max-width: 1024px; // max size of container
  width: 100%; // 100% between min and max ;)
  min-width: 960px; // lowest toggle point
}
.left { 
  width: 80%; // 80% of above
  float:left;
  min-width: 500px; // add a min-width to declare stopping point
}
.right { 
  width: 20%; // 20% of above
  float:right;
  min-width: 100px; // add a min-width to declare stopping point
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your divs are equaling more than 100% of your parent try this and edit it as you see fit

If you post your html I can explain it furthur

set your body to an absolute value example `body{width:1200px}` then set your first media query to `@media screen and (max-width: 1199px){body{width: 100%}}` This way you know that anything over 1199px the page will break

Comment: i updated the post, because was not clear at all, my problem is that if i'm doing all width in %, my right column should not go down, should be rezised and keep his position or i'm wrong ?

Comment: Without your media queries and html its hard to tell you your exact issue